# SPGroupCollection not recognizing new Users groups

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am trying to search sharepoint groups of a particular User, but the below code is not recognizing recently added users. It says he is not in groups even if he is in groups

```
SPGroupCollection collGroupsUser = oUser.OwnedGroups; // (group count as zero)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the property [OwnedGroups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser.ownedgroups.aspx), as it is named, countains Groups the user owns.
If you want to know in what groups he belongs, use the property [Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser.groups.aspx)

Comment: Is there any time it takes to recognize new people? even when i use "Groups" it is taking some time to recognize. Also if that user never logged in before, i am not able to see his groups

Comment: hum... I did not know that. Do you use AD Groups inside SharePoint Groups ?

Comment: its my mistake, i referenced "Users" instead of "siteusers"

Comment: @Chuck: If Goglue's answer is what you needed, you can accept it.